# 2D Transformation of points in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, coordinate-system

I have a table of points with x and y coordinates in UTM along with other attributes. I need to display these points in a local system for which I do not have the parameters. I however have the coordinates of two control points (A1 and A2) in the local system and I have used a GPS to obtain their UTM coordinates as well. Is there a way  to carry out a 2D transformation of the points in ArcGIS 10 using the coordinates of the two control points in both systems?

NB: This can be done in surpac from 2d transformation as str file under file tools but it eventually turns up as  line features whereas I need the output as point features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you will want to use the Spatial Adjustment tools in ArcMap to accomplish this.

Take a look at the following documentation link to learn a bit about the tool:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-spatial-adjustment.htm

The Spatial Adjustment toolbar will let you essentially conduct vector georeferencing using the control points data sets you have.  You will need to specify spatial adjustment transformations.  See here for documentation explaining the differences between the methods:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-spatial-adjustment-transformations.htm

From what I understand of your situation you will likely want to use a Similarity transformation method which scales all features as one (rather than independently).  Additionally it only requires you to have a minimum of two control points.  The tool does recommend that you have three or more control points though to increase accuracy.

In order to use the tools, it should be as simple as opening both the Editor and Spatial Adjustment toolbars in ArcMap and entering an edit session for the target feature classes.  Then you can use the Spatial Adjustment toolbar to test out some transformations.